# How to Configure Circle CI or Jenkins for Multiple Environments in Digital Ocean

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, digital-ocean, circleci

We have made an app, we deployed out production branch , testing branch, development branch on different Digital Ocean Droplets. But I want to set up CD for them using Jenkins or Circle CI ( whichever the one which would be easier and better ).

How would I be able to create CD environment for all these branches, would I need to do set up for each branch seperately ?.

For example - If I make use of Jenkins to set up CD pipeline, then would I need to set up Jenkins seperately for dev, uat, and prod environment ?.

I am feeling really confused about it, please let me know the clear structure of how can I set up proper CD environment for all these branches on Digital Ocean droplet.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is via triggers on where the commit was made

i.e.

1. If a PR is created then you run a CD job that deploys this PR code to your testing droplet [or create one for this PR]
2. Once the PR is merged to develop - deploy develop to your staging droplet
3. Once develop is promoted to mainline - then deploy it to production